# Is there a "thickness" node?

Tags: node-editor

I'm looking for a node that will return a white value for the thickest part of an object (as seen from the camera), fading off to black as the thickness becomes 0. Does such a thing exist?

I'd like to simulate an opaque light without needing caustics, so my idea is that center of the object would be the brightest part with the outer edge being darker.

Comment: I don't think there is such a node, but if you explain a bit more how you were planning to use it, maybe someone could find an alternative...

Comment: Is this just a volumetric effect? You can use emission in volumetrics as well.

Comment: Oh, really? I didn't know that. I'll give it a try.

Comment: The geometry node or the light path node with the  thickness output might help.

Answer (score 3):

Is *Vector Math* set to *Length* close to what you need?

You can invert it (or not) with a *Map Range* node, and then the *From Max* parameter becomes a slider for you to control where the effect terminates.

[image]

[image]

Something I cooked up using this:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize this was from '17, oh well.

Comment: Thats totally fine. Old unanswered questions get bumped to the homepage to get answers. :)